# UserWarning: This pattern is interpreted as a regular expression, and has match groups

Tags: pandas, expression

Given the following pandas DataFrame -

| **json_path** | **Reporting Group** | **Entity/Grouping** | **Entity ID** | **Adjusted Value (Today, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)** | **Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)** | **TWR Audit Note** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | William and Rupert Trust | 9957007 | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Cash | - | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1] | Barrack Family | Gratia Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | 55491732.66 | -0.971018847 | -0.971018847 | 11.52490309 | 55491732.66 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income | - | 18469768.6 |  |  |  | 18469768.6 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[1] | Barrack Family | High Yield Fixed Income | - | 3668982.44 | -0.205356545 | -0.205356545 | 4.441190127 | 3668982.44 |  |

I try and save only rows that contain 4x occurances of `.children.[]` using the following statement - 
**Code:**    `perf_by_entity_df = df[df['json_path'].str.contains(r'(\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}')]`

However receive the following:
**Error:**`UserWarning: This pattern is interpreted as a regular expression, and has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.`

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the code below to suppress the warning:

```
perf_by_entity_df = df[df['json_path'].str.contains(r'(?:\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}')]
```

Replace:

```
r'(\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}'
```

By:

```
r'(?:\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}'
#  ^^-- HERE: Non capturing group
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-16):

> **(?:...)**
>
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.